# Loading external algorithms into program from text file c++

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm

I'm beginning a project and am looking for a little guidance before I start making major decisions.

The project is a network simulator. Basically I will load a directed graph representing a network of computers. The network is expected to run an algorithm to simulate an operation for the network as a whole. Each separate node on the graph will run the same algorithm.

For example: A simple flooding algorithm which begins at a root node, and each node should be able to receive the message then resend it to its neighbors.

My issue is the loading of algorithms for each node to run. The user should be able to create a text file with the algorithm and have it load into my program for each node to run separately.

The text files can be in any format, although I believe it would be easiest if they were formatted as a c++ function.

The only idea I could come up with would be to create a parser to read each line. Not only would that be difficult but I don't think that would work due to loops present in most algorithms.

I'm willing to give a more detailed description.

Comment: If you want a scripting language, embed a scripting language. [Lua](http://www.lua.org/), for example, is very easy to embed into a C++ app.

Comment: Have you considered using a scripting language such as Python, Lua or even JavaScript?

Comment: basically, you want to execute some external code (from the node's POV) : why not using system(), WinExec') ou CreateProcess() ?

Comment: [Possibly related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3513352/1084416)

Answer (score 2):

Usually, if you want to write code in files, you'd use a scripting language. [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) is a popular one.

Your description of parsing a text-file for an algorithm, is basically you creating your own scripting language (which is also commonly done).

Perhaps you don't need a full-blown scripting language, but at the very least, you need a [domain-specific language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), and might as well use a scripting language (sandboxed) for that purpose. [Boost::Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/) is an option for describing and embedding your domain-specific language parser directly in your C++ code.

Comment: I would also recomend Lua.  There is a nice tutorial at http://csl.name/lua/ to get Lua executing in C++.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions with Lua. I looked at the tutorial Nick posted and it looks promising. Would the algorithms being loaded in be written in Lua? Also would the nodes be able to communicate with each other given they are basically a Lua shell?

Comment: Yes, the algorithms would be written in Lua, which is similar syntax to the 'C' family of languages. The nodes will be able to communicate... if you write it that way. Basically, your C++ code calls the Lua scripts, and you can have the Lua function calls execute C++ functions (or Lua functions). So: C++ executes Lua which can call your C++ again. You can 'expose' (write functions for) your C++ nodes and C++ data and C++ functions, and the Lua scripts can interact with the nodes and write algorithms for the data (as one possible way of doing it). Lua can do anything your C++ lets it do.